# I'm getting the error "queue.on is not a function" in the "discord-player" library

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I ran into this error while making the VC automatically exit if there are no people or there are no songs in the queue.

I confirmed that there were no problems with other codes, and also checked the discord.js and discord-player versions. I also deleted the node_modules folder and ran the npm install command.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders")
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
const { QueryType } = require("discord-player")

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("play")
        .setDescription("loads songs from youtube")
        .addStringOption(option => option.setName("song").setDescription("URL을 입력하여 노래를 추가합니다."))
        .addStringOption(option => option.setName("playlist").setDescription("플레이리스트 형식의 노래를 추가합니다."))
        .addStringOption(option => option.setName("search").setDescription("제공된 키워드를 기반으로 하여 노래를 검색 후 추가합니다.")),
    run: async ({ client, interaction }) => {
        if (!interaction.member.voice.channel) return interaction.editReply("이 명령을 사용하려면 음성방에 있어야 합니다.")

        const queue = await client.player.createQueue(interaction.guild)
        if (!queue.connection) await queue.connect(interaction.member.voice.channel)

        // Check if the voice channel is empty or the queue is empty, if so, leave the channel
        queue.on('channelEmpty', () => {
            queue.destroy()
        })
        queue.on('queueEnd', () => {
            queue.destroy()
        })

        // Add this line to make the bot leave the channel when there are no more songs in the queue
        queue.on('botDisconnect', () => {
            interaction.followUp({ content: '음성 채널에서 나갑니다.' });
        })

        let embed = new MessageEmbed()
        let url = interaction.options.getString("song") || interaction.options.getString("playlist") || interaction.options.getString("search")
        let searchEngine = QueryType.AUTO

        if (interaction.options.getString("song")) {
            searchEngine = QueryType.YOUTUBE_VIDEO
        } else if (interaction.options.getString("playlist")) {
            searchEngine = QueryType.YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST
        }

        const result = await client.player.search(url, {
            requestedBy: interaction.user,
            searchEngine: searchEngine
        })

        if (result.tracks.length === 0)
            return interaction.editReply("검색 결과 없음")

        const songOrPlaylist = result.playlist || result.tracks[0]
        await queue.addTracks(result.tracks)
        embed
            .setDescription(`**${songOrPlaylist.title}** 대기열에 추가되었습니다.`)
            .setThumbnail(songOrPlaylist.thumbnail)
            .setFooter({ text: `Duration: ${songOrPlaylist.duration}`})

        if (!queue.playing) await queue.play()
        await interaction.editReply({
            embeds: [embed]
        })
    },
}
```

This is the play.js file

Comment: maybe they should be `client.player.on` instead (after a cursory look at documentation)